# XAML binding to property of owned object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight, binding

I am programming a Silverlight application. My MainPage object owns another object that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and has the bool CLR property IsIncluded:

```
public partial class MainPage: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    CustomObject customObject = ... // was created successfully

    CheckBox checkBox = ... // is actually created in in XAML

    // this is only for testing purposes
    public bool IsIncluded
    {
        get { ... }
        set {
            // ...
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsIncluded"));
        }
    }
}

public partial class CustomObject: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool IsIncluded
    {
        get { ... }
        set {
            // ...
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsIncluded"));
        }
    }
}
```

My MainPage.xaml contains

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsIncluded,Mode=OneWay}" />
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=customObject.IsIncluded,Mode=OneWay}" />
```

The first binding works fine. The second not. I need the second to work. How can I achieve that?

Comment: `CustomObject customObject = ....` looks like a private field and you cannot bind to fields. If that's the case you need to convert it to **public property**

Comment: public CustomObject customObject with property changed

Comment: If `customObject` is assigned *after* the binding has been wired-up via the XAML then you will need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the `MainPage` class for the `customObject` property also (you may have done this already, but if so it is not in the code you posted).

Answer (score 0):

```
CustomObject _customObject = ... // was created successfully
    public CustomObject customObject
    {
        get { return _customObject ; }
        set {
            _customObject  = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("customObject"));
            }
    }
```